# What is a Sanity Suite?

Tags: terminology, definition

I read an article about Test Driven Datamigration ([German, PDF](http://www.zuehlke.com/fileadmin/pdf/fachartikel/132_os_map_test_datenmigration.pdf)) and they mentioned a Sanity Suite. It is not well explained and there's no definition.

Is there a definition or is it a spongy word?

Comment: See edit comments for rational on rollback

Comment: Thank you LFSR, one less abuse to rollback. Good edit.

Comment: @Rich - NP, let's get in the habit of throwing some rational around for these type of things.  I think the community will pick it up quickly.

Comment: @LFSR: Thanks. You can monitor his rollbacks here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jargon

Comment: @LFSR: He started this tantrum here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586882/what-is-the-difference-between-a-port-and-a-protocol

Comment: @Rich - Actually I think this is the only one that fits the bill for not falling under the definition of jargon, DAL, ORM, l18n, lValue & downward-funargs are all very specific domain words

Comment: Funny, I was going to cite that as the place where you decided to start vandalizing questions based on a personal vendetta.

Comment: @LFSR: I thought that the difficulty of finding a domain-relevant definition via Google made it likely to qualify as jargon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a small set of unit or integration tests, just to check sanity -- that the system basically works.

It can be useful to extract such a suite from your larger suite of automated tests for rapid testing when you don't have time for the full suite.

In practice, the sanity suite is often all that is developed, though it is better than nothing.