# Relation or Correspondence between Protocol and Port Number in URL

Tags: networking, protocols, port

Port Number is the logical connection to a specific software on the hardware machine. Then there should be a relation between the set of softwares in the Web Server and the Port number used in the Requested URL. However, it seems that there is a relation between Port No and the Application Layer Protocol (from [Internet Protocol Suite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_Suite)) used such as HTTP (80), FTP (21), Telnet(23), etc.. Why is it so??

I referred a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586882/what-is-the-difference-between-a-port-and-a-protocol) on stackoverflow. As answered by Aaron Maenpaa, there is not a strict one-to-one correspondence between a Protocol and a Port. It is just a convention used. We can have HTTP listen on some other port as well (say 8080). Then how can we do it??

This leads to another question.
How do we map a custom server program to some non-standard TCP port number?

Answer (score 0):

Any application can `bind()` to any available port, with the exception of low-numbered ports which may require administrative privileges.  There is absolutely no enforcement of what type of application listens to what port number, just convention.  That's because the port number itself is just a 16-bit field in the packet headers and there is no practical way for the operating system to know what is going on at the application level.

Typically, the port number an application listens to is determined by the application itself: it has to decide what port to hand to the `bind()` call.  External to an application you can use NAT (Network Address Translation) in a router or firewall to redirect any port number to any other port number.

Note that TCP ports are completely independent from UDP ports.  An application using TCP port 12345 has absolutely nothing at all to do with an application using UDP port 12345.  A firewall which allows or blocks one does not automatically allow or block the other.

Unfortunately, this point is often confused by the fact that IANA (keepers of the unenforced conventions as to what applications use what port numbers) has decided to assign service names to both UDP and TCP ports even if the service only uses one of them.

Comment: Here what do you mean by an application. The one deployed inside the Container right? Eg. With Tomcat, the application is one deployed inside webapps. Then how can I configure Port number for my application?

Comment: "Application" simply means a process running on the system.  The port number is determined by the `bind()` system call.